# Using or not using DEBUG conditional define

Tags: delphi, build-process, delphi-2009, conditional-compilation

I had an idea to use FastMM4 in FullDebugMode when compiling my project with Debug Build Configuration.

When I chose the Debug build configuration the Delphi automatically sets up DEBUG as a conditional define. So, this code should work as expected:

```
unit uXTrackUpdater;

program Test;

uses
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}FastMM4,{$ENDIF}
  Forms;

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.Title := 'Test';
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmTest, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
```

And it works. However, when I change the build configuration to the Release configuration. This code also works! And it should not? Since the DEBUG conditional should not be defined.

So, could somebody explain me why this code executes regardless of the build configuration and how to setup it properly (in a way that FastMM4 would be compiled only when using debug configuration).

**After Edit**

With FastMM it was only an example. Before posting here my question I've tested it on different case. Here it is:

```
program Project21;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  {$IFDEF DEBUG} SysUtils; {$ENDIF}

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E:Exception do  //should not be found after rebuilding with RELEASE build configuration
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

The code above, will compile no matter of build configuration. Why?

**After second edit**

I know, that others saying that my examples are working as expected. But they are not working for me. I've checked this behaviour on Delphi 2010 and it is identical (still not working).

Maybe this will be helpful: I've replaced `DEBUG` directive with `RELEASE` to see what will happen. The result was that `RELEASE` causes that my example code **will not build** in both configurations.

Third edit:

My dproj file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{E9F0DC1F-23EC-46AA-97F8-68C007E77218}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectVersion>12.0</ProjectVersion>
        <MainSource>Project21.dpr</MainSource>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
        <DCC_DCCCompiler>DCC32</DCC_DCCCompiler>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <DCC_DependencyCheckOutputName>Project21.exe</DCC_DependencyCheckOutputName>
        <DCC_ImageBase>00400000</DCC_ImageBase>
        <DCC_UnitAlias>WinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE;$(DCC_UnitAlias)</DCC_UnitAlias>
        <DCC_Platform>x86</DCC_Platform>
        <DCC_E>false</DCC_E>
        <DCC_N>false</DCC_N>
        <DCC_S>false</DCC_S>
        <DCC_F>false</DCC_F>
        <DCC_K>false</DCC_K>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>false</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
        <DCC_Define>RELEASE;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>0</DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>
        <DCC_DebugInformation>false</DCC_DebugInformation>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DelphiCompile Include="Project21.dpr">
            <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
        </DelphiCompile>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Base">
            <Key>Base</Key>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Debug">
            <Key>Cfg_2</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Release">
            <Key>Cfg_1</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')"/>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType/>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality>
                <Source>
                    <Source Name="MainSource">Project21.dpr</Source>
                </Source>
                <Parameters>
                    <Parameters Name="UseLauncher">False</Parameters>
                    <Parameters Name="LoadAllSymbols">True</Parameters>
                    <Parameters Name="LoadUnspecifiedSymbols">False</Parameters>
                </Parameters>
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1045</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1250</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
            </Delphi.Personality>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Of course it "works". What's there not to work? Or did you mean "it includes FastMM4 even in the RELEASE build"?

Comment: If you don't include FastMM4 in your project, Delphi will use its own default memory manager. Hence the code runs in RELEASE too.

Comment: Your second code example clearly *doesn't* work in all build configurations. Please copy and paste *real* code that you've compiled and *confirmed* to represent the claims you make about it.

Comment: @Rob This is the real code. Why would I bother to submit something different? The code works for me in both configurations on Delphi 2009.

Comment: If that's true, then both configurations define DEBUG. Without DEBUG defined, you'd have a syntax error — a `uses` clause without any units in it, and without a semicolon.

Answer (score 6):

When using conditional compilation, make sure you *always* do a build after switching configurations. Apparently the current set of "defines" is not part of the key that's used to test if a certain unit needs recompilation or not. If all you changed is a define (ie: DEBUG is no longer defined), the compiler simply doesn't know about it, and keeps using the pre-compiled unit.

But since this is about FastMM4, there's an other way: You can define `InstallOnlyIfRunningInIDE` for both DEBUG and RELEASE and FastMM4 will not install it's memory manager unless you're running from the IDE.

---

#### Edit

Given your later edit, I assume your project's configuration is to blame, because IFDEF's work just fine. Inspect both branches of your configuration options, very that you don't have "DEBUG" defined for both Release and Debug.

Comment: `InstallOnlyIfRunningInIDE` can be useful but I never use it because I want to get leak detection etc. for my debug builds even when I don't have a debugger attached.

Comment: I always rebuild my project after switching configurations. I've updated my qestion.

Comment: @Cosmin, Regarding your edit: I've checked this few times. Also, I don't have any conditional defines in Base configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that DEBUG is defined on Base configuration (which is supposed to have the common compilation settings). When you change Base, all non-modified settings default to Base values.

Verify if you doesn't put DEBUG on Base configuration instead of Debug config by accident.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any conditional defines in Base configuration.

Comment: Well, I said that because it happened to me, months ago .